# id doesnt get passed (MVC dropdownlist + viewdata selectlist)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

**my view:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Person"))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Departments",ViewData["Departments"] as SelectList)
    <button type="submit">Select</button>
}
```

**my DepartmentController:**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Departments"] = new SelectList(db.Departments, "ID", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```

**my PersonController**

```
 public ActionResult Index(string id = null)
        {

            if (id != null)
            {
            //Return list of persons with department id
            }
          return View();
        }
```

**My problem:**
When I select a department from the DropDown and press the button, it redirects fine, but the id is not passed.
What am I missing? I'm guessing it has to do with how i fill the DropDownList?
Anyway, as always, thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of `@Html.DropDownList("Departments"` use `@Html.DropDownList("id"`

Comment: Thanks alot!, can't believe it was that easy, you were first so i'll mark yours as an answer if you create one.

Comment: Give it to AlexArt. Also read his suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name attribute of your dropdown is not "id" so the MVC model binder can not bind it.
Add html attribute new {@Name ='id'} to your DropDown definition and it should work.

I also would suggest that your view receive a model - in this case model binding will be much easier, and you could use DropDownFor helper.

Using model also allows you to avoid using ViewData and ViewBag containers that are not recommended because they are not strongly typed so if by mistake you write ViewData["Departnents"] in your View you won't get a compilation error because of the typo, but clearly it won't work.

As an opposite you can define a model

```
public class Person
{
    public SelectList Departments {get; set;}

    public int SelectedDepatrmentId {get; set;}

    //Other person properties come here

}
```

In your View the only thing you should do to make it work is:

```
@model path to your Person class

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDepatrmentId, Model.Departments)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case that mvc model binding is done with **name** attribute and `@Html.DropDownList("Departments"...` will render html with dropdown having name `'Departments'` so either try my first answer or change `@Html.DropDownList("Departments"...` as shown in my second answer.

Try This :

```
public ActionResult Index(string Departments) // <------ Use 'Departments' here instead of 'id'
 {
    .....
    return View();
 }
```

OR change `dropdownlist` as :

```
  @Html.DropDownList("id",ViewData["Departments"] as SelectList)
```